# How to snapshot a SQL Server Database without taking it offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We occasionally want to copy our production database *with data* and have it populate a corresponding database in our test environment so that we can reproduce production problems.

We currently wait for a maintenance window and do an Detach/Attach.

We're using SQL Server 2008 and both test and production databases are on the same server.

What is the best way to copy a snapshot that would 1) not require the production database to go offline and 2) be capable of being automated via a build script?

Comment: Please clarify - Detach/Attach or Backup/Restore?  Detach/Attach requires the instance to be offline; Backup/Restore does not.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - you should really just turn that kind of comment into an answer.  I've seen so many of your SQL comments that I would just upvote if they were answers!

Comment: @OMG Ponies - sorry, Detach/Attach.  Editing and up-voting your comment.

Comment: @womp You can upvote comments you know? And It's probably best to let comments be comments and answers be answers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a backup. You should do anyway... and you can do the restore overriding file and database name and file positions.

> both test and production databases are
>   on the same server.

Bad idea. I ahve seen SQL scripts grind a SQL Server to a halt and I would not like to happen that on a production system. I suggest using your backup server for testing.

Comment: +1: yes, moving to different servers.  just launching this company.  thanks for the answer.